# How do I learn and improve my writing skills once fully immersed in a language?

Tags: writing

As the title says, I'm fully immersed in a second language. I use this second language all the time (thinking, reading and writing) but my writing skills aren't up to scratch. Any ideas on improving writing skills?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but unfortunately it is too broad (because it covers *all* aspects of grammar), like the question [What strategies can students use to learn grammar when studying independently?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/462/800). Please also check [How can I put grammar rules into flashcards?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2500/800) and [Is it possible to learn grammar through spaced repetition, and if yes, how?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3399/800).

Comment: You may also be interested in some of the [numerous other questions about `grammar`](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).

Answer (score 2):

Writing skill is one of the most important skill for learning language, and you said you are already immersed in a language so keep try hard. If you focus on increasing your writing skill, I would recommended you:

- Find some writing book and practice writing from that, that is the best way but only one problem is some book they might be the old version and can't find new knowledge from there.
- Learn from YouTube, this is the basic resource like you can learn and can follow and practice from there but we don't know that we are writing correct or not.
- Another way, if you love to learn though online resource, I am using Write Me, within this app it has the perfect animation to show you the sequence of writing then you can follow it and practice as much as you can from there, I picked it by practicing on the app, it literally helped me a lot in practicing writing.

Answer (score 0):

Since writing is an active skill that involves grammar, vocabulary and word choice, punctuation and spelling, it takes a lot of time and practice to improve it. Since you are already immersing yourself in the language, the only way to improve is by practicing a lot and being patient (don’t give up because if you try hard it is only a matter of time before you start to see some results!). As for some methods that focus on the improvement of your writing skills, here are some suggestions:

- Revise some grammar from time to time (especially if you have some doubts about a rule in particular).
- Keep an English dictionary near you so you can clarify the meaning of some words and find some synonyms  so as not to repeat words or phrases.
- Reread what you wrote in order to see if you can highlight and correct some mistakes you may have made.
- When you read something that you find interesting (for example a book, a post on a blog or an article), you can underline some words or phrases that you liked and see if you can create similar ones with different words.
- Keep a diary in English so you can turn writing into a routine activity (moreover, you can write about anything and experiment with a wide range of words and topics).
- Try to chat with native speakers so you can ask for some clarification concerning any doubts that you may have and do some practice at the same time (for example, you can search for a language exchange partner).